# How is JavaScript evaluated at the target page in an AJAX situation?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

This may be a philosophical question.

Suppose you're making an AJAX request to a page (this is using Prototype):

```
new Ajax.Request('target.asp',
{
 method:"post",
 parameters:{alldata:Object.toJSON(myinfo)},
 onSuccess: function(transport){
   var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
   alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
 },
 onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
});
```

Now suppose on the target page, the server -- using ASP -- generates some JavaScript based on the myinfo object you sent it, and you are interested in the resulting JavaScript.  My guess is that, since this target page is never seen by a browser (where the JS interpreter lives), the JS isn't evaluated.  And it will only *be* evaluated if it is returned to the calling page and evaluated *there*.  Is that the point?

Thanks for screwing my head on straight for me.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right.

Comment: The transport variable will contain the response from the server, normally this wouldn't be expected to be a full HTML page but more likely a fragment or data (JSON, XML, etc). What are you trying to achieve? It's probably a better question than this esoteric approach.

Comment: It's an application internal to my small team of developers that helps to manage builds for tools under CVS source control.  The jist is that we're at a point where we want to do some work on the server (cvs commits, stuff like that) and send back to the calling page the results of that work.  So the Requesting page tells the server to do some stuff, and the Worker page does the stuff and sends the info back to Requesting page.  So the server needs to accept the request, process it, and format the results to send back to the Requesting page.  I'm taking this opportunity to learn new web tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the assumption is right. The response of that Ajax request is just a string. And that needs to be interpreted somehow that the JavaScript that’s embedded in that response is also interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

The JS on the target.asp page is not evaluated in the client unless you eval() it or push it into the DOM or something.

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all comfortable with ASP, I'll say that up front...

If the server is generating javascript, it would be as a string. As such, it would need to be written to the DOM in some way in order to be meaningful (I'm including the ajax script when I say DOM).

BUT!!!

I know that ASP and .NET are really weird and like to put hooks and callbacks all over the place. In theory, ASP *does* speak javascript and thus might have some js interpreter of it's own. But I try to sleep at night by thinking that the folks at MS would NOT allow their *server-side* scripts to execute anything that is intended for the client-side.

Short answer: yes, if the code isn't written out to the page, the code shouldn't be executed. You should be encoding your server's output to be on the safe side, simply because it's a good practice (changing `<` to `&lt;`, etc).